# Extend Property with isDirty

Tags: javascript, typescript, properties

I want to track changes to the properties of my classes in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) so that I only update the fields in my database which have actually changed. Currently, I am using an array where I add properties when they change and then I iterate through the array to determine what fields changed and need to be updated in the database. However, I would prefer to do this with some sort of isDirty check.  My thought is that I would be able to call something like `if (property.dirty) then {}` to determine if a property has changed.

I remember being able to do something along these lines in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), but it's been a while and I can't remember exactly what we did in that codebase.

Is the desired code below possible?

### Current Code

```
class test{
  private _ID: Guid;
  private _dirty: Array<{}>;

  get ID(): Guid {
    return this._ID;
  }
  set ID(id: Guid) {
    if (this._ID != id) {
        this._ID = id;
        this._dirty.filter(function (f) { return f.Field == "id" }).length > 0 ? this._dirty.filter(function (f) { return f.Field == "id" })[0].Value = id.toString() : this._dirty.push({Field: "id", Value: id});
    }
  }

  get Name(): string {
      return this._Name;
  }
  set Name(name: string) {
      if (this._Name != name) {
          this._Name = name;
          this._DirtyFields.filter(function (f) { return f.Field == "ccseq_name" }).length > 0 ? this._DirtyFields.filter(function (f) { return f.Field == "ccseq_name" })[0].Value = name : this._DirtyFields.push(new EntityField("ccseq_name", name, FieldType.String));
      }
  }
}
```

### Desired Code

```
class test{
  private _ID: Guid;

  get ID(): Guid {
    return this._ID;
  }
  set ID(id: Guid) {
    if (this._ID != id) {
        this._ID = id;
        this._ID.isDirty = true;
    }
  }

  get Name(): string {
      return this._Name;
  }
  set Name(name: string) {
      if (this._Name != name) {
          this._Name = name;
          this._Name.isDirty = true;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was to create a Field class that I then used as properties in my Objects.

## Field Class

```
export class EntityField {
    private _Field: string;
    private _Value: any;
    private _FType: FieldType;
    private _isDirty: boolean;

    constructor(field: string, value: any, fType: FieldType) {
        this._Field = field;
        this._Value = value;
        this._FType = fType;
        this._isDirty = false;
    }

    markClean(): void {
        this._isDirty = false;
    }

    markDirty(): void {
        this._isDirty = true;
    }

    get isDirty(): boolean {
        return this._isDirty;
    }

    get Field(): string {
        return this._Field;
    }
    set Field(field) {
        if (this._Field !== field) {
            this._Field = field;
        }
    }

    get Value(): any {
        return this._Value;
    }
    set Value(value: any) {
        if (this._Value !== value) {
            this._Value = value;
            this._isDirty = true;
        }
    }

    get FType(): FieldType {
        return this._FType;
    }
    set FType(fType: FieldType) {
        if (this._FType != fType) {
            this._FType = fType;
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
export class Entity{
  public Name: Field
}

Entity test = new Entity()
Entity.Name.isDirty() // Returns False
Entity.Name.Value = "Test";
Entity.Name.isDirty() // Returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can add a property to an object so it's not a problem to do this:

```
this._ID.dirty = true;
```

Even when `Guid` doesn't have this `dirty` member.
The problem of course is typescript which will complain because of that.
To avoid that you can simply do:

```
private _ID: Guid & { dirty?: boolean };
```

---

#### Edit

Again, javascript already supports it, you can do this:

```
obj.dirty = true;
```

For any js type: booleans, strings, arrays and even functions.
But for having support for that in typescript you can do this:

```
interface Object {
    dirty?: boolean;
}
```

But be aware that you are adding this to **all* of the objects that you have in your code. As you're not actually changing the prototype it won't have any effect in runtime, but typescript-wise it will effect all instances.

Comment: This works great for my Guid Properties, but I also have Properties that are string, boolean, Array, etc.  Any thoughts on how to add a dirty field to those?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you edit your question and include more code and/or explain?

Comment: I added more details to the question.  I want to be able to set the `isDirty` field on any type of property.  So `[string].isDirty = true` or `[boolean].isDirty = true`

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: When I add the code `interface String {isDirty?: boolean;}` I get a run-time error `TypeError: Cannot create property 'isDirty' on string 'Employee Name'` for the line `this._EmployeeName.isDirty = true;`

Comment: Are you using a module system (that is you use import/export)?